# Integration with Facebook Lead Ads

Tags: facebook

Someone knows or has made some integration between Facebook Lead Ads and CiviCRM?

I'm looking for a custom integration as described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/

Answer (score 1):

Is my [Facebook Conversion Tracking Pixel](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/civicrm-facebook-conversion-pixel) extension what you're looking for?

Comment: I suspect not. I'm looking for a custom integration as described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/. So that when someone fills out a Facebook Lead Ad form, through a webhook, this information can be entered into CiviCRM.

Comment: @FrancescBassasiBullich I'm looking for the same. Have you found or developed an extension?

Comment: @masetto I finally found nothing and for lack of resources I left this route.